# Show Training Iteration Score for Logistic Regression Classifier sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm making a text classification using Logistic Regression classifier in sklearn.
it's working really nice. but now I'm curious about something.
is it possible to show training score for each iteration when the Logistic Regression train?
for example I'd like to show the training score for each iteration in format like this:

```
Iteration 1: 50% 
Iteration 2: 53%
...
Iteration 10: 86%
```

does anyone here can help me about this matter? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the output the way you want it to. At the best you can set `verbose=10` while initializing the classifier as `clf = LogisticRegression(verbose=10)`. This will just make the iterations of the `LibLinear` or the `Libfgs` solver verbose. You can set `verbose` to any positive integer. In case of the `liblinear` solver you can see an output as follows:

```
[LibLinear]
iter  1 act 1.107e-01 pre 1.107e-01 delta 4.189e-01 f 2.079e+00 |g| 5.541e-01 CG   2
iter  2 act 2.825e-06 pre 2.825e-06 delta 4.189e-01 f 1.969e+00 |g| 2.547e-03 CG   2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmmm. then what does the value mean? like what are the values next to act, pre, delta, f and |g|? and what is the value next to CG? :) can you please explain it to me?

Comment: These seem to be the values of the parameters during the Convex Optimization process. Unfortunately, there is no great documentation for this. Somebody has opened an issue [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/issues/23), to which the author of the library suggests to read the [this paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/logistic.pdf).